# If r is a primitive root, then the residue of $r^t$ is also a primitive root if $\gcd(t,\phi(m))=1$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, primitive-roots

This is part ii of the proof of Proposition 6.77 of Gerstein's *Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs*. I don't understand it. Here is how the discussion, and my understanding of it, go:

$r$ is a primitive root

$(a,b)$ represents $\gcd(a,b)$.

$Z=\{x\mid (x,m)=1 \land 1\le x \lt m\}$

Suppose $(t,\phi(m))=1$. Then $r\equiv (r^t)^x$ for some $x$. I see this.

Since $r$ is equal to its residue, we have the residue of $(r^t)^x$ equal to $r$.

Then they go on to state "... hence *every* element of $Z$ is congruent to a power of $r^t$." I don't see this. They may be applying part i, which says

$Z$ consists of the residues of the powers of $r^t$ with $1\le t \le \phi(m)$

This would imply that $r\in Z$, which we already knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) is

> ... $g$ is a **primitive root modulo $n$** if every number $a$ coprime to $n$ is congruent to a power of $g$ modulo $n$.

Since it's stated that $r$ is a primitive root modulo $m$, and $Z$ includes only numbers coprime to $m$ in $[1, m-1]$, for each element $y$ of $Z$ there's an integer $s$ where

$$y \equiv r^s \pmod{m} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using what you stated, i.e., $r \equiv (r^t)^x = r^{tx} \pmod{m}$ for some $x$, in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$y \equiv (r^{tx})^s = r^{txs} = (r^t)^{xs} \pmod{m} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: OK, so every element of Z is congruent to a power of $r^t$. Do we know that if every element of Z is congruent to a power of r then r is a primitive root? Gerstein only states the converse, i.e. if r is a primitive root then Z consists of the residues of the powers of $r^t$

Comment: @AnnaNaden I added a specific definition from Wikipedia's article and a bit of other details to my answer. A primitive root is defined to be *any* integer, say $z$, such that every coprime integer to $m$, i.e., element of $Z$, is congruent to a power of $z$. Thus, since $Z$ consists of the residues of the powers of $r^t$, then $r^t$ would also be a primitive root. Note there may be multiple, non-congruent primitive roots modulo $m$.

Comment: Gerstein defines a primitive root differently: "If the multiplicative order of a is equal to $\phi(m)$ then r is a primitive root." Perhaps you, or the Wikipedia article, will explain why the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: @AnnaNaden The two definitions are equivalent. First, note if $\gcd(a,m) = 1$, then $\gcd(a^n,m) = 1$ for any positive integer $n$. Next, the definition of multiplicative order is the smallest positive integer $u$ where $r^u \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. Also, the definition of Euler's totient function, $\phi(m)$, is the number of integers in $[1,m-1]$ which are coprime to $m$. In addition, each $r^v$ for $1 \le v \le \phi(m)$ is not congruent modulo $m$ to any other $r^w$ for $1 \le w \le \phi(m)$ since, otherwise, $r^{v-w} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. Thus, $r^s$ for $1 \le s \le \phi(m)$ maps to $\phi(m)$ ...

Comment: @AnnaNaden (cont.) integers $1 \le i \le m$ where each is *distinct* modulo $m$ and coprime to $m$. Since there are $\phi(m)$ such integers in that range, this means each coprime integer must be mapped to, in some order, by a power of $r$. Thus, by Wikipedia's definition, $r$ is a primitive root.

Comment: (Tried to move this discussion to chat but the link just takes me back to the question).  You are starting with Gerstein's definition and deriving the Wikipedia definition, is that right? You have shown that if $a\in Z$ then all powers of a are in Z and that $\phi$ is the number of distinct residues of powers of a, right? I don't follow the rest of your comment. Where do you use the requirement that the order of a is the *smallest* power?

Comment: @AnnaNaden You're correct I showed how Gerstein's definition can be used to derive the Wikipedia one. As for using the order of $a$ is the *smallest* power, it's in my first comment's $2$nd last sentence, i.e., "In addition, each $r^v$ for $1 \le v \le \phi(m)$ is not congruent modulo $m$ to any other $r^w$ for $1 \le w \le \phi(m)$ since, otherwise, $r^{v-w} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$". Sorry, I could have made this more clear. If $w \neq v$, where $w \gt v$, but $r^w \equiv r^v$, then $r^{v - w} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. This means the order must be $\lt \phi(m)$, contradicting it being $\phi(m)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112429/discussion-between-john-omielan-and-anna-naden).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly is going on in the proof that you quoted because the quote is incomplete. If you don't mind a different proof, then I recommend proving and using the more general fact that $$\text{ord}_{n}(a^k)=\frac{\text{ord}_{n}(a)}{\gcd(k,\text{ord}_{n}(a))}.$$ It is pretty easy to see from this that the powers of a primitive root $g$ modulo $n$ that are also primitive roots are exactly the $g^k$ such that $\gcd(k,\varphi(n))=1.$